# joining multiple shapefiles using PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I'm attempting to batch join/merge multiple shapefiles (approx. 1.3m features each) to one main shapefile using PyQGIS.
The structure of every shapefile is similar to the below (the spelling errors are correct):

| ElemlentID | Maxim(m/s) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2.411 |
| 2 | 26.33 |

The main shapefile should appear as something similar pending on the quantity of tables:

| ElemlentID | Maxim(m/s) | Maxim(m/s)1 | Maxim(m/s)2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2.411 | 12.784 | 1.455 |
| 2 | 26.33 | 11.717 | 5.44 |

Based on previous websites, answered questions and the QGIS doc, I've created the following:

```
# Define layer tree root and group
root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
layer_group = root.findGroup('Layer group')

# Define main layer and common fields from main layer and layers stored in group
main_layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('1pc merged')[0]
main_layer_field = 'ElemlentID'
childField = 'ElemlentID'
iter = 1

# Iterate through each layer in group and join to main layer using defined fields
for layer in layer_group.children():
    print(layer.layerId()+" and "+str(iter))
    joinObject = QgsVectorLayerJoinInfo()
    joinObject.setJoinLayerId(layer.layerId())
    joinObject.setJoinFieldName(childField)
    joinObject.setTargetFieldName(main_layer_field)
    joinObject.setJoinFieldNamesSubset(['Maxim(m/s)'])
    joinObject.setUsingMemoryCache(True)
    main_layer.addJoin(joinObject)
    iter=iter+1

print("finished")
```

[console log of the above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pVYV.png)
[layers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLqv0.png)

This appears to work, no errors are thrown but from what I can gather the data is never added to the main_layer aka '1pc_merged'.
I've used various print lines to confirm layers and ids are defined correctly, checked alternative code and commenting out sections, but still nothing.